# Tensorflow install not working (Core dumped)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've installed tensorflow in ubuntu20.04 LTS, but it has failed.

I'm using a Virtualenv for python3.9, so I use pip command and not pip3

First I upgraded pip, and then I installed tensorflow

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow
```

Then if I open python3.9 and run

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

the error I get is

```
>>> Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed tensorflow in the virtualenv? Have you activated your virtualenv before running `import tensorflow as tf`?

Comment: Yes, I activated the virtualenv. If I don't, the error I get is "no module named tensorflow". I'm getting the 'core dumped' error

Comment: This might help: https://tech.amikelive.com/node-887/how-to-resolve-error-illegal-instruction-core-dumped-when-running-import-tensorflow-in-a-python-program/

Comment: That did not work for me, I tried «pip install tensorflow==1.5» and it gave me the error «ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.5 (from versions: 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2, 2.5.0rc3, 2.5.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.5»